# iTerm2 color scheme: use alternative background color (41m)

Tags: zsh, colors, iterm2

I have set up iTerm2 to change its profile when I ssh to a specific machine. This works as intended (I am using `zsh` and `oh-my-zsh`).

The main thing I do for this is in my `~/.zshrc` file:

```
echo -e "\033]1337;SetProfile=<profile_name>\a"
```

This sets the colors as defined in "Colors" in iTerm2's "Profile". So far, so good.

I have downloaded the [color profile called "Harper"](https://iterm2colorschemes.com/) and would like to use it with the "41m column" (in lack of a better term). As far as I understand that basically means I have to set the terminal's background color to "red" (which is what "41m" means).

But I cannot figure out how to do this...

I have tried (for example):

```
echo -e "\033]1337;SetProfile=<profile_name>\a"
echo -e "\033]1337;SetColors=bg=c00\a"
```

or

```
echo -e "\033]1337;SetProfile=<profile_name>\a"
echo -e "\033]1337;SetColors=bg=f00\a"
```

Which makes iTerm show a red background and use (for example) the foreground colors defined in the Harper color scheme. But that's not what I want.

My question is very similar to (not to say the same) what was asked in a Stackoverflow question: [Iterm2 colors - using the 42m or 41m options](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34257198). But that question does not have an answer.

By the way, I know that most instructions on the Internet seem to use a different OSC command (50 instead of 1337), but according to [iTerm2's documentation](https://iterm2.com/documentation-escape-codes.html), that is outdated:

> The OSC command 50 used to be used but it conflicts with xterm, so it is now 1337.

Is it even possible to do what I intend?

Answer (score 0):

I think I misunderstood how this works. The columns (e.g. 41m) show, how text that would be output with a specific background color would look like. But as long as the console does not output text like this, the colors are not used.

The "background color" is the background of the text, not the background of the shell.